# How to run firebase services in a different process?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my android application, I am trying to use firebase services in a different process(not thread). I added process name in all services used by firebase.

```
 <service
            android:name=".firebaseclient.CCTFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:process=":fcmProcess">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".firebaseclient.FirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:process=":fcmProcess"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I should receive a call back in FirebaseInstanceIDService's method:-

```
 public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}
```

But I am not getting any callback.In addition to this Firebase is getting initialized in the main process of application which might be causing this?

Please help me in getting callback to onTokenRefresh method.

Comment: It should work. Print this refreshed token and check again. And to find an issue, show both of your firebase classes CCTFirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIDService

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/sIogPuUsC50/E1vB-hnTCAAJ) answer, you should avoid putting Firebase on a second process.

BTW you could try initialize the Firebase instance manually in the second process using

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context context, FirebaseOptions options)
//or
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context context, FirebaseOptions options, String appName)
```

Reference documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions)

PS: I never tried that, so i can't be sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Any FirebaseApp initialization must occur only in the main process of the app. Use of Firebase in processes other than the main process is not supported and will likely cause problems related to resource contention.

ref form:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions)

so final we cant not do it.